# Resizing VLCJ PixelWriter

Tags: java, javafx, vlcj

Standard question for VLCJ is HOW to get resizable video for JavaFX.... What reason is there for not having this functionality. I have been working on it for DAYS, any help would be greatly appreciated....

```
            @Override
            public void display(DirectMediaPlayer mp, Memory[] memory, final BufferFormat bufferFormat) {
                final int renderFrameNumber = frameNumber.incrementAndGet();
                currentByteBuffer.set(memory[0].getByteBuffer(0,memory[0].size()));
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = currentByteBuffer.get();
                        int actualFrameNumber = frameNumber.get();
                        if (renderFrameNumber == actualFrameNumber) {
                            canvas.getPixelWriter().setPixels(0, 0,
                                    bufferFormat.getWidth(),
                                    bufferFormat.getHeight(),
                                    byteBgraInstance, byteBuffer,
                                    bufferFormat.getPitches()[0]);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("[FINE] "
                                    + " - Skipped late frame "
                                    + renderFrameNumber
                                    + " (actual = "
                                    + actualFrameNumber + ")");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Pretty much I can get the video in the original size, but not scale or size to fit anything else. Does anyone have experience with PixelWriter and copying it a second time to a scaled image or ANYTHING?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the JavaFX approach with vlcj requires the so-called "direct-rendering" media player (as you are using in your question).

This direct rendering media player uses LibVLC's video rendering callbacks to make available each frame of video for your application to render in whatever way it sees fit.

The way the native API works is that you must first provide callbacks to set the desired video buffer format - this includes the picture format, but also includes the width and height you want for the video buffer.

This native callback is invoked once *before* video starts playing, and never again (unless you stop the video playback and start it again).

Clearly, this means that the native video buffer dimensions are fixed once the playback has started and can not be dynamically resized on the fly.

That answers the first part of your question as to why the functionality does not exist - it's simply not supported by the underlying native library.

What vlcj gives you is access to the 'raw' native video buffer, it is then up to you how you want to render it - whether you use BufferedImage, an OGL Texture or indeed PixelWriter. It is also up to you how you scale it if you need to support that. Scaling in software is going to increase your CPU load of course.

On this second part of your question I can't really advise any more than that.

Unrelated to your specific question... but after looking at your posted code I am not sure about the synchronisation semantics you have there - inside your "run()" method, there is nothing I can see preventing the native video buffer from being overwritten. The latest version of vlcj-javafx demo project required for Java8 uses new native buffer lock/unlock methods that should be used to provide proper synchronisation.

Comment: Do you know of a swingnode implementation that would allow me to use an embeddedplayer in my JavaFX?

Comment: If there was such a thing, it would be dead easy. What I do for things like this is the other way around, I have a Swing app in which I can use my embedded media player (using a java.awt.Canvas) and then I embed a JavaFX component inside my Swing app. It's not ideal of course.

Comment: But JavaFX is currently becoming the main way to interact with the GUI for Java as far as I can tell. It has made its way into the core Java, tools are being built for it. I wouldn't be surprised if it over takes Swing soon.... It seems to be better crafted with observable properties and binding. No need to re-write code. In my case the whole application is JavaFX I just want to play resizable video...

Comment: You have to compromise. Use the video playback provided by JavaFX with all of its limitations, or use the video playback provided by LibVLC/vlcj with its different limitations. Anyway, there may yet be a way to software scale from the native LibVLC byte buffer, but I don't know what that is.

Comment: I can quite easily write a software-scaling resizable video application just by using BufferedImage and a Graphics2D context, so something similar must be possible in JavaFX. It's not ideal again, but like I said working in this area requires compromises.

Comment: Is there ANY example of rewriting the code to a BufferedImage? I would be willing to try and port the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for this for a while and even tried resizing the rgbBuffer manually that I have at some point in my code. But now I have an approach that works for me.

Instead of using a `Canvas` I used an `ImageView`, which works better for resizing because it has native implementation to do so. I've seen comments of people saying `PixelWriter` on images is slow, but that was either a long time ago or their computer is just slow. I don't seem to have any problem with it (yet ;) ); it's fast enough for me.

Create a normal `Pane` (or preferably, subclass it and add the rest of your code in there). This pane can be resized using your normal code.

Inside the `Pane`, add an `ImageView` and bind it to the width and height of the parent pane. Assign a `WritableImage` to the `ImageView` and use the `PixelWriter` from the `WritableImage` to write pixels to your image.

The following class demonstrates the resizable image and acquiring the `PixelWriter`.

```
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelWriter;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class ResizableVlcPlayer extends Pane {

    private ImageView mImageView;
    private WritableImage mWritableImage;
    private PixelWriter mPixelWriter;

    public ResizableVlcPlayer() {
        mImageView = new ImageView();

        // this auto resizes the image when the pane resizes
        mImageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
        mImageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(heightProperty());

        getChildren().add(mImageView);

        mWritableImage = new WritableImage(1280,720);
        mImageView.setImage(mWritableImage);

        mPixelWriter = mWritableImage.getPixelWriter();

        // Continue normal implementation by writing to the PixelWriter
    }
}
```